# OneSignal Push Notification - Doesn't work on WP8.1

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, onesignal

Just created a project today, added with this references:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/windows-phone-sdk-setup

Toasts and Internet Services are enabled.
I've inserted the OneSignal.Init code sample to the OnLaunched event and changed the ID to mine.
My solution associated with store.

Debug/Release mode:
New users successfully registered to my app. (I can check them in the Users menu on my OneSignal Dashboard.)

My problem:
When I'm trying to send a Push Notification to all users, the website(OneSignal) just keep sending. I've tried it on 4 WP emulators, but I didn't get notifications.

Anyway, Microsoft Azure Notification HUB works fine...

Software: VS 2015 with every update installed.

If anyone knows what I've missed, please help me:)

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

On Windows Dev Center -> Your App settings -> Services -> Push Notifications -> WNS/MPNS -> Live Services site!

Generate new Secret Code, and then activate it. (Use it on the Dashboard of Onesignal App Configure)

Onsignal SDK: Using the notificationOpened event is must have!

After that, you can the notification when the app isn't in focus.
To see that while using the app, you should create a local toast notification with the datas from Onesignal event.